# Controller not loading if javaScript containing controller code is added dynamically to HTML dom

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is a example code: 
I have following code at the end of html body

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var js = document.createElement("script");
    js.src = "forms/dynamicForms/sampleFormController.js";
    document.body.appendChild(js);
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp']);
</script>
```

When I run my app, sampleFormController is not found, if I inspect body tag in Chrome, script is added as a child tag to body tag.

where as when I modify code and add timeout it works

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var js = document.createElement("script");
    js.src = "forms/dynamicForms/sampleFormController.js";
    document.body.appendChild(js);
    setTimeout(myFunction, 2000);
    function myFunction() {
    angular.element(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp']);
      });
    }
</script>
```

Is there a way to make my first code to work without adding timeout?

Comment: requireJS would fit your requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the *onload* property of the script tag to `myFunction()`. Refer to the [MDN page on HtmlScriptElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement) for more information and an example similar to the modified code snippet below. Also, see it utilized in [this example plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/HDoDa4u0XM3cNFzbZlVa/).

Similarly, you can set the *onerror* property to a function for handling the case when an error occurs. And because this code is asynchronous, you could use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)- see [this example](https://gist.github.com/ThomasBurleson/5674241).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var js = document.createElement("script");
    js.src = "http://elliott.andrewz.org/data/sampleController.js";
    document.body.appendChild(js);
    js.onload = myFunction;
    function myFunction() {
        angular.element(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp']);
      });
    }
</script>
```